# Groovy - Why does a 1-digit string get casted as a character to an int?

Tags: groovy, types

The following code outputs the surprising value of `51`

```
    int a = "3"
    println a // outputs 51
```

Groovy seems to interpret the `3` character as an `int` and carry on.

Why does groovy not throw a `ClassCastException`? And how can I stop groovy from ignoring these kinds of typing mistakes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `int a = "3"` uses Groovy type coercion and auto-converts "3" to char and converts it to the ASCII integer value of 51. Only behaves like this for a single digit number as a string (two or more digits will generate a runtime error). This statement has the same results as `int a = (char)"3"`. This type of silent bug can be nasty but type checking can detect errors like this.

In Groovy, you can enable static type checking at class or method level.

```
@groovy.transform.TypeChecked
void run1() {
    int a = "3" // triggers type-check exception 
    println a
}

@groovy.transform.TypeChecked
void run2() {
    def a = '3' as int
    println a // outputs 3
}

run1()
run2()
```

The static type checking forces a strict [compile-time type check](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/#_the_code_typechecked_code_annotation).

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\java\groovy\Example.groovy: 3: [Static type checking]
 - Cannot assign value of type java.lang.String to variable of type int
 @ line 3, column 10.
        int a = "3" // triggers type-check exception
            ^
```